# ToOptimizedResult on an HttpResult causes a StackOverflow exception

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text, servicestack-bsd

I'm using v3.9.56.0 and I'm encountering a stack overflow exception when I call `ToOptimizedResult` (Called from my own service runner) on a returned `HttpResult` from a service. When I dig deeper I found the exception was coming from the `JsonSerializer`.

Here is the snippet of code for what is being returned:

```cs
return new HttpResult(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(path, file)), true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `ToOptimizedResult` expects to receive a DTO response object that it can compress to create a `CompressedResult` response.

However you are providing an `HttpResult` which effectively is wrapper for the `byte[]`/`string` DTO response object of the file you are loading, this wrapper is a complex type, and isn't really what you want to be trying to optimise.

If your file is binary then you should return the `byte[]` of the contents, if it is plain text then return a `string`. Then the `ToOptimizedResult` can optimise that data.

```cs
// Binary file type
return File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, file));  // returns byte[]

// Plain text file type
return File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, file));  // returns string
```

Comment: I kind of thought this might be the issue, but wasn't sure. I wonder if there is a good way to determine when to optimize a HttpResult.

Comment: @kinstephen You shouldn't ever optimise an `HttpResult`. In most cases DTO object responses should be optimised where possible. It should only be avoided where the client doesn't support optimised formats, but that is checked in the method.